# How to rename bundled static files(ProjectName.style.css and blazor.server.js) in The Blazor App

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor, static-files, blazor-webassembly

I wanna hide that i use The Blazor.

so, I should modify name of bundled css and js files.

How to do this?

Comment: As far as I know, the blazor.server.js file is an embedded resource on the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.dll assembly, which ships as part of the ASP.NET Core shared framework. In my opinion, there is no way to modify it.

Comment: Is ProjectName.styles.css file same that too?

Comment: Could you please tell me the type of you have used?  Client or Server side?

Comment: I am using in Client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#css-isolation-bundling), CSS isolation occurs at build time. During this process, Blazor rewrites CSS selectors to match markup rendered by the component. These rewritten CSS styles are bundled and produced as a static asset at {PROJECT NAME}.styles.css, where the placeholder {PROJECT NAME} is the referenced package or product name.

That means we could only disable the bundle not modify it during develop environment.

But after publish, it will generate the file like this:

[image]

You could modify the `{PROJECT NAME}.styles.css` to `{other}.styles.css` and modify the index.html css name as below:

```
<link href="{other}.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: Thanks to the your answer.

Comment: But, My published application files list different to the your attached image. In my case the index.html and the {PROJECT NAME}.styles.css didn't exists. Did you try in webassembly project? I am working on The Blazor Server.

Comment: You used blazor server side project?

Comment: Oh, Yes. I selected menu named 'Blazor Server App' when i create my project project on The Visual Studio. I was confused. Because of I am working on the style and script parts.

Comment: As far as I know, the server app doesn't contain the app css by default. If you set it as razor.css , it will as same as the client app setting.

Comment: Oh, Thank you Zhang~!. I modified css default path by use StaticWebAssetBasePath. so, after publish project and i got css file. And follow your above answer. thanks~

Comment: To add a little - you can use an MS build task (probably AfterBuild) to rename the compiled css file the framework will give you. With this, you get that to happen automatically instead of doing it manually.